# Disable notifications for mode changes

Tags: irc, pidgin

When someone assigns me a +o it triggers the status icon to blink, as if someone "pinged" me by `Carpetsmoker: Hello` or sent me a private message.

For example:

```
(13:36:09) mode (+o Carpetsmoker ) by Juice-Man
```

Can I disable this for modes assigned to me? I don't care about them and the extra notification is annoying. I've looked through the preferences and plugin list, but I don't see an option for this.